# Vulkan 1.3 Render Pass Instance clarifications

Tags: vulkan

According to the spec, with Vulkan 1.3 we get access to some new (seemingly quite exciting) features, including two command buffer functions:

```cpp
void vkCmdBeginRendering(VkCommandBuffer, VkRenderingInfo*);
void vkCmdEndRendering(VkCommandBuffer);
```

... a new enumeration:

```cpp
enum VkRenderingFlagBits {
    VK_RENDERING_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS_BIT,
    VK_RENDERING_SUSPENDING_BIT,
    VK_RENDERING_RESUMING_BIT
};
```

And finally, we get a couple of structs (fields omitted for brevity):

```cpp
struct VkRenderingInfo;
struct VkRenderingAttachmentInfo;
struct VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo;
```

From reading the extension [VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering.html) (core since Vulkan 1.3):

> This extension allows applications to create single-pass render pass instances without needing to create render pass objects or framebuffers. [...]

My main questions are:

- Can we scratch the need for render passes from our applications?
- Can we scratch the need for framebuffers from our applications?
- Is there some drawback from adding a `VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo` to the pNext chain of `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo`, instead of a render pass?
- What does the term "*dynamic*" imply in "dynamic rendering"?
- What does "*single-pass*" imply in the above quoted description for dynamic rendering?
- Will we still need to create and manage render passes and framebuffers with Vulkan 1.3? (examples may be provided)

There exists practically no information (that I could find) on these topics.

Answer (score 3):

The point of dynamic rendering is to be able to bypass the render pass model. So yes, if you use dynamic rendering, you can bypass the render pass model.

The principle downside is that you *bypass the render pass model*. They didn't create that model for no reason, after all. For tile-based renderers especially, knowing the structure of rendering can significantly improve performance in specific cases. If you're using deferred rendering with a single render pass, the implementation can fully understand how you intend to use the images. It can keep gbuffers in tile memory, sometimes for the entire render pass, which saves performance since you don't have to ever write them out to memory.

But, if you're *not* working with a TBR of some kind, then that doesn't really matter.

Comment: So the render passes are mostly relevant for TBR's? I can understand the idea of being more explicit up front, but render passes create a combinatorial nightmare (somewhat mitigated by added dynamic states) and - at least for me - it feels like everything becomes very tightly coupled: Render pass, pipeline, framebuffer, command buffer recording..

But let's assume we are not on a TBR - when would you recommend the use of render passes?